# XML validation: Concurrent unordered and occurrence requirements in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

In XML Schema (XSD 1.0), I have following requirements for four elements:

1. **element1** will appear always first, with minOccurs = 0 and maxOccurs = 1
2. **element2** will appear with minOccurs = 0 and maxOccurs = 1
3. **element3** will appear with minOccurs = 0 and maxOccurs = unbounded
4. **element2** and **element3** will appear in any order (after element1 and before element4)
5. **element4** will appear always in the end with minOccurs = 0 and maxOccurs = unbounded
6. All of these elements are children of a **parent_element**, and as all of them have minOccurs = 0, but at least 1 of them should be present in the parent element.

I have created a scheme which fulfills all requirements except **#2** and **#6**. In my schema element2 and element3 can appear in any order, but I am unable to restrict element2 to occur only once. Also, I am unable to make sure at least 1 element is present in the **parent_element**.

Review my schema below and suggest the updates to fulfill all of the above requirements.

```
<xs:element name="parent_element">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="type1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <xs:element name="element2" type="type1" />
                <xs:element name="element3" type="type1" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="element4" type="type2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In order to fulfill requirement #2 I tried a trick of using `maxOccurs="1"` with element2 (inside choice) but it did not work and element2 was still able to be repeated more than once in any order with element3.

```
<xs:element name="parent_element">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="type1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <xs:element name="element2" type="type1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="element3" type="type1" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="element4" type="type2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements #4 and #6 preclude use of XSD 1.0.

XSD 1.1 can meet these requirements via `xs:assert`:

### XSD 1.1 Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="parent_element">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="element1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
            <xs:element name="element2" />
            <xs:element name="element3" />
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="element4" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(element2) &lt; 2 
                          and (element1 or element2 or element3 or element4)"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The solution in XSD 1.0 would be preferable.

Comment: As I mentioned: *Requirements #4 and #6 preclude use of XSD 1.0.*